# Possible to present UIViewController from another app?

Tags: ios, xpc

This may seem overly ambitious, but I'm exploring the ability to present a view controller from one app in a separate app (both authored by me). I'm not talking about reusing a class, I'm referring to literally presenting a controller from another process over the foremost one.

I believe this is in the realm of XPC on macOS, and how share extensions currently work on iOS. Unfortunately I'm not looking for a share controller though.

Is this at all possible (even using private APIs if I have to)?

Comment: Would you expect the reused view controller to be controlled by the other process or by the app presenting it?

Comment: @ReinSpijkerman It would have to be controlled by the other process.

Answer (score 1):

Because both apps are sandboxed by iOS, there is no way for either of them to locate and load (something from) the other. Extensions are the only way provided by Apple to have another app perform some action.

Using private APIs will not lift sandbox restrictions. With a jailbroken device, it would be possible to locate the other app. In that case `-[NSBundle loadClassNamed:]` would allow you to obtain and instantiate a class from a loaded (application) bundle, but it would still be controlled by the process that instantiated it.

So, no, what you ask is not realistically possible for apps that would be distributed to other users than yourself. If it's just for yourself, you might be able to get somewhere with a lot of work on creating, controlling and communicating between processes on jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own server, then this is possible. Just have app1 send a trigger to your server, and then your server sends push notification to your app2. when user tap notification, it will open your app2 viewcontroller.

Comment: I've thought about something similar, but leveraging URL schemes.

Comment: That would definitely work. Good luck with ur app. :D